# How to return data as Promise type in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, promise

How to return data as Promise type in Angular 2?

Using this function I need to return data as promise type:

```
private getStudyPeriods(): Promise<CurrentPeriod> {
    let data = [];
    return data;// here
 }
```

I tried last variant like this:

```
public getStudyPeriods(): Promise<Period[]> {
    return this.education.get(7).then((data: any) => {
      if (!data.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
        this.periods = data;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          resolve(this.periods);
        });

      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: So do you want to return a Promise or an Observable?

Comment: Sorry Promise, fixed

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just return a `Promise` the resolves itself immediately.

```
private getStudyPeriods(): Promise<CurrentPeriod> {
    let data = [];

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private getStudyPeriods(): Promise<CurrentPeriod[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let data: CurrentPeriod[] = [];
        resolve(data);
    });
}
```

I changed return type to array, since it seems you are trying to return an array of CurrentPeriod, rather than just one.

Comment: But if I get data from another Observer how to return this to current Promise? I mean this: `public getStudyPeriods(): Promise<Period[]> {
    return this.education.get(7).then((data: any) => { new Promise (data)});`

Comment: then you wrap it in a promise  and you get the data from the observer, then resolve(yourDataHere). Whatever is entered in resolve method will get returned to the promise.

Comment: Also, you aren't using an observer. You are using a promise. this.education.get is a promise, not an observable.

Comment: I need to get data from observer and pass this through promise